# How can I combine two sql with not exists?

Tags: mysql

I doubt it can be right to solve.

test_table:

```
id       |  name   |  value  |  date
---------|---------|---------|------------
1        |  john   |    32   |  2016-01-08
2        |  tom    |    590  |  2016-01-03
3        |  king   |    1903 |  2016-01-01
4        |  john   |    490  |  2016-01-02
5        |  gary   |    58   |  2016-01-18
6        |  cat    |    5    |  2016-01-10
```

sql1:

```
select name,sum(value) as val from test_table where val > 500 group by name;
```

sql2:

```
select name from test_table where  date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) group by name;
```

I want combine two sql in one. The sql result name is not exists in sql2 name  result  collection.

update:

sorry for my confused describe.

The sql1 is scan whole the table, it aim to find out who's total value is greater than 500.

The sql2 is scan last week's data to find out who exists last week.

So, I Want combine two sql , to find out those people who's total value is greater than 500 but not exists last week.

sorry again for my poor English.

update - add example:

just like the table content,the result should be :

john,tom,king

because their total value is > 500,but not update last week

But how can I do it.

Thanks all.

Comment: what you are trying to say in this line -> The sql result name is not exists in sql2 name result collection.?

Comment: @VigneswaranS it means the sql result is not exists in sql2 result.I want to find out who not update lastweek but his value is greater than 500. Thank you,The problem describe already update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, sum(value)
FROM test_table
WHERE value > 500
AND name NOT IN (
    SELECT name
    FROM test_table
    WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
)
GROUP BY 1
```

OR

```
SELECT name, sum(value)
FROM test_table
WHERE value > 500
GROUP BY 1
HAVING max(`date') < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

If you are trying to having sum(value) > 500, delete above lines

```
WHERE value > 500
```

And change **AND** to **WHERE** for the first SQL

And add this line at end of each of above:

```
having sum(value) > 500
```

Comment: Thank you for answer , but your sql result is to find out  the user who's value greater than 500 before last week. but i just want to find out who exists before last week.

Comment: I have simplified your question, i think my solution is exactly same as your requested

Comment: I add the example just now, for my table content,the result should be john,tom,king,but your sql result is just tom and king.so, I want who not update last week , not who last week value > 500 and not update.

Comment: because in your original SQL you said : where value > 500 , i thought you ignore any value <=500. are you actually try to say: sum(value)>500 ?

Comment: I just see that,sorry for my careless,and thank you for perfect solution,

Answer (score 0):

It is really helpful to describe what you want, as well as providing SQL samples.  You seem to want the sum of values greater than 500 for names that have no row with date in the past week.

If so:

```
select name, sum(case when value > 500 then value else 0 end)
from test_table
where value > 500
group by name
having max(date) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ;
```